# CAD SDK suggestion for Android IOS Web and desktop to read write DWG files

Tags: cad, dwg

We are planning to build a CAD based product in Web,mobile (Android and iOS), web and desktop. IS there any commercial library to ready/ write 2D/ 3D cad data to and from DWG files?

Please suggest me some. Is Unity a good choice for displaying CAD/ GIS data.

Answer (score 1):

Consider for working with DWG files:

- [Autodesk Real DWG](https://www.techsoft3d.com/products/realdwg)
- [ODA Drawings SDK (ex Teigha)](https://www.opendesign.com/products/drawings)

and for rendering (as CAD alternative for Unity):

- [HOOPS Visualize](https://www.techsoft3d.com/products/hoops/visualize/)
- [ODA Visualize SDK](https://www.opendesign.com/products/visualize)